# OS X can a pop-up menu be displayed from a CALayer?

Tags: macos, user-interface, core-animation, calayer

Is there a way to display a pop-up menu such as an NSMenu object from a Core Animation layer?

Answer (score 0):

No. Layers are lower level objects than NSView objects. You can't put a view in a layer.

In OS X, layers are an optional part of a view. (In iOS, **every** view is backed by a layer)

You can go the other way, though, and ask for a view to be layer-backed, and then add additional layers to the view.